# Swagger cannot find user schema using Yaml files

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger

Beginner here using swagger. I try to create a simple endpoint documentation. But I cannot figure what is wrong with my schema type.

I started by creating the folder structure: In my root src, I have the swagger config file in typescript format:

- I referenced the API and Schame path using path module.

```
import swaggerJSDoc from "swagger-jsdoc";
import path from 'path';

const userSchemaPath = path.join(__dirname, 'middlewares', 'validators', 'userSignup.swagger.yaml');
const userRouter = path.join(__dirname, 'routes', 'user.swagger.yaml');


const options: swaggerJSDoc.Options = {
    definition: {
        openapi:    '3.0.0',
        info: {
            title:  'Chat app with Sockets.io and HTTP',
            version: '1.0',
            contact: {
                email: 'sasdansss***iel9@***.com',
                name: 'Daniel Mihai'
            }
        },
        servers: [
            {
                url: 'http://localhost:3001',
                description: 'Local env server. Localhsot...'
            }
        ]
    },

    //Array of API routes
    apis: [userRouter, userSchemaPath]
}


const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);
export default swaggerSpec;
```

[image]

Next, In the router I started to build the yaml for the router endpoints for users.

```
# User setup...
paths:
  /api/user:
    post:
      tags:
        - Users
      summary: Signup user. Create an account for the Chat application
      description: User is prompted to create an account for the application. User is required to use an unique email for the account.
      operationId: createUser
      requestBody:
        description: Fill all the fields and use a POST request /api/user to create a user.
        content: 
          application/json:
            schema: 
              $ref: '../middlewares/validators/userSignup.swagger.yaml'
            required: true
      responses:
        '201': 
          description: User created successfully
        '400':
          description: Invalid parameters provided. Zod validator responses
        '500':
          description: Something went wrong with the server. Or email duplicate error
```

**Error here finding the schema...**
I use morgan logger and get a 404 error for the reference schema... I dont understand whats wrong with it because I don't get any syntax wrong. I checked also with ChatGPT and it points me to things that I already checked (check the path)...
`::1 - - [06/Feb/2024:14:41:13 +0000] "GET /middlewares/validators/userSignup.swagger.yaml HTTP/1.1" 404 30`

Next, I build the schema for the zod validator:

```
components:
  schemas:
    UserSchema:
      type: object
      properties:
        email:
          type: string
          description: Unique email required to create an account 
          example: daniel@gmail.com
        firstName:
          type: string
          description: first name 
          example: Daniel
        lastName:
          type: string
          description: last name 
          example: Michael
        password:
          type: string
          description: password will be hashed 
          example: MyPassword
```

**Other localhsot swagger specs:**
I don't see the parameters:
[image]

I also don't see the schema:
[image]

However, In the bottom of the screen page, the schema works:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Apparently the reference to the yaml file is done by the config file...
because in my config file I used path to refference the file, in the ref I corrected the following:
 `$ref: '#/components/schemas/UserSchema'`

So in my understanding, the ref is looking in the file already specified in the APIS array from my config file `apis: [userRouter, userSchemaPath]`...

The ref will look for components and schemas:

```
components:
  schemas:
    UserSchema:
      type: object
      properties:
```